# Типы в паскале

Tags: pascal

Сижу, разбираюсь в паскале. Запнулся на такой мысли: для переменной мы пишем тип, допустим, integer, а если пользователь введет переменную большее число этого диапазона? Программа будет работать? И можно ли сразу писать тип лонг, если некритично память тратить?

Comment: Такими темпами скоро люди будут осваивать программирование с доисторического QBasic`а.

Comment: @Asen  
> Такими темпами  
  
То есть раньше все начинали с Java и C++?

Comment: @VioLet, ну да, как же.

Answer (score 2):

Работать будет, но значение будет остатком от деления введенного числа на верхнюю границу диапазона типа.

Вообще, ты бы мог это посмотреть и без проверки ввода. Сделай переменную integer и присвой ей большое значение, потом выведи на экран.

Comment: лучше тренероваться на кошка... байтах (byte), так понятней будет

Answer (score 2):

Написал такой код:

```
var
n: integer;
begin
    n := 213124311124121;
writeln(n);
end.
```

Вывод: -30567

Как видите если тип переполнить, то результат будет неожиданным.

Comment: Прям уж не ожиданным ?) Если понимаешь почему так, то результат отнюдь не не ожиданный :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну введет,и что с того?

я как понимаю ты только начинаешь программировать, вот когда дойдешь до проверок того что вводит пользователь, тогда такие вопросы и стоит задавать, а сейчас они как-то бессмысленны.

Для паскаля ничего не критично кроме динамических списков, но ты до них доберешься, если вообще доберешься, через год полтора :)

Comment: ПОЛТОРА ГОДА?? а нужно ли... паскаль для меня как для начинающего.месяц два. потом на питоне буду учиться работать.

Comment: @Shrek, ахаха, ваш тонкий троллинг заслуживает уважения =)

---
@алексей74732107, а вы как хотели? Я тоже начинал с паскаля, и скажу, что осваивал его, именно осваивал месяцев, эдак, 7-8. Тогда я еще был рад и этому. Вам же, думаю, придется не меньше.

Comment: Я если честно, паскаль изучал в тереме, годо 2,5 и параллельно изучал делфи, php, c.

А зачем изучать паскаль, который нигде тебе не пригодиться? Начни с того языка к которому стремишься, который сейчас где-то используется!
Паскаль дпже не ООП а просто строчный язык, который только и умеет по строкам код читать, а ну да можно модули писать свои, но опять же строки, строки, строки и ничего интересного, хотя для практики программирования он подходит. я на ZXSpectrum'e начинал программировать, там вроде как Бэйсик был.


2 @Asen ну не совсем троллинг, но... есть что-то.

Comment: да вот как раз и посоветовали с ооп не начинать...почему не знаю. поясните?

Comment: @алексей74732107, чтобы не забивать голову ненужной ДЛЯ НАЧАЛА информацией. Сначала надо получить базовые знания: научиться строить алгоритмы, писать процедуры и функции (разумеется узнать, чем одно от другого отличается), узнать элементарные типы данных и тд и тп. Паскаль, кстати, отлично для этого подходит. А только потом уже начинать работать с ООПовскими "тремя китами".

Comment: Кстати в том же php процедур нет. и практически на многих языках используются только функции.

Comment: @Shrek, нет, паскаль все-таки объектный язык, такой же, как и C++. Синтаксисом эти два языка вовсе не похоже, но структурами данных и типами очень. Так, например, эквивалент struct в си => это record в паскале, классы есть и там, и там( в смысле, в C++, а не в си ), вот только их определение несколько отличается.

---
А что насчет Delphi, то тоже хотел бы сказать, что выражение 

    Я учу Delphi.

=

    Я учу Visual Studio 2010

В дельфи крутится тот же паскаль, модифицированный паскаль - Object Pascal.

Comment: @Asen, когда VS скатится в такую же клоаку неиспользования, в которой сейчас находится RAD Studio, тогда можно будет сказать "Я учу Delphi = Я учу Visual Studio 2010".  
Ничего не имею против RAD'a, так как сам сейчас работаю в Delphi XE2, но ситуация с ним действительно печальная :(

Comment: @Asen Про "Я учу Delphi.= Я учу Visual Studio 2010" вроде бы уже не верно, с какой-то версии борланд стал утверждать что delphi это не только среда, но и название их диалекта object pascal